# Can I connect a step up converter for higher voltage with nine 3000mAh cells in parallel, or is it dangerous and doesn't work like that?

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, heater

I'm a college mechatronics engineer student who is working on a production project about making an electrical device (like a toaster, alarm clock etc.) My device is a simple nichrome wire heater and needs to be charged (handheld) which means it need a bunch of batteries to get the proper amount of watts needed (around 500 W.)

If I do that I would need to connect 9 cells in series plus 9 cells in parallel then connect both of them. This is a problem since it takes a lot of space and costs a lot.

I was wondering if I could use a step up converter on one hand and connect it to only 9 AA cells instead of 18 AA.
The transformer would take less space and be cheaper while giving more voltage.

Is it possible to connect a step up converter with 9 cells in parallel or will the current and voltage difference cause it to melt or explode?

Comment: Welcome! You can’t use a transformer with DC at all, so no.

Comment: For stepping up DC (from a battery) you'd need a boost converter.

Comment: The power you need is the issue.Both low voltage high current battery and high voltage low current battery are relatively low power, and combining them really doesn't help. You're looking at something like a 12V 100Ah battery (can supply the 40-50A you need for about 2 hours), either lead acid or better, LFP like https://shopsolarkits.com/products/renogy-12-volt-100ah-smart-lifepo4-battery-rbt100lfp12s-g1

Comment: @brhans I assume this is some sort of kinetic artwork...

Comment: "AA" defines a form factor for an electrochemical cell.  While there are probably cells out there, marketed as "AA", from which you could briefly get 55W / cell, they wouldn't be found on the shelves of a supermarket.  Please _edit your question_ to tell us **what exact cell** you are planning on using.  If you mean "An AA cell from the supermarket" then say that -- and then go find a datasheet for an Energizer or Rayovac AA alkaline cell, and see how much power you could get out of one.

Comment: something similar to this:
https://www.amazon.com/POWEROWL-Rechargeable-Batteries-Capacity-Discharge/dp/B07M7JGTP7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't get 500 W from 9 AA batteries.

The power of 500 W still has to come from batteries if you want 500 W power into heater, no matter what conversion circuit there is.

9 AA batteries in series is 13.5 V. To provide 500 W power, you need to get 37 A from the batteries.

The problen is, AA batteries can barely give out even 3 A into a short circuit, so you would indeed need more than 10 packs of 9 batteries to get 37A at 13.5V.

If you put 9 AA batteries in parallel, that might give you a 1.5V pack which could provide maybe 80 A into a dead short circuit, but for 500 W you need 333 A at 1.5V

You can now use the formula P = U × I where P is the 500 W you need and you can assume each AA battery is 1.5 V and can for the sake of computations provide 3 A which is likely not realistic even.

So each battery provides 4.5 W max so you need 111 batteries for 500 W, no matter how you connect them or convert their voltages.

500 W / 1.5 V = 333 A = total 111 batteries in parallel.

500 W / 3 A = 166 V = total 111 batteries in series.

500 W / 15V = 33.3 A = 10 series batteries, 11 in parallel, 110 batteries total, 495 W.

500 W / 13.5V = 37 A = 9 series batteries, 12 in parallel, 108 batteries total, 486 W.

Comment: Well, there are cells in an AA form factor from which you could get 55W / cell.  Briefly.  But long enough to win a poorly-worded bet, I'll bet.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum power that an AA alkaline cell* can produce is about 2 W. To achieve 600 W, you will need about 300 cells, *regardless of how they are connected*. And, still, the cells with discharge after less than one hour.

Therefore, your plan to use only 81 AA alkaline cells will not work: the cell voltage will sag so much that they won't power your load. Regardless of how they are connected. Regardless of using a converter.

Your desire to use only 9 AA alkaline cells will fail even more miserably.

If you want to power 600 W in a portable way, buy a large power bank capable of at least 600 W and with an output voltage that matches your load's ideal voltage.

However, let's step back and look at the big picture:

> nichrome wire heater

There is a reason we rarely use batteries for portable heating: bulky, expensive, and the charge doesn't last long. That's why for portable heating we normally use fuels (such as propane), not batteries.

(*) You didn't say you're using alkaline cells, but you said "AA" and that normally means AA size alkaline cells.

Comment: I was going to use AA-size rechargeable batteries with 1,5 V and 3000mAh rating.
The heater will only be on for an hour.
Let's round up 18 batteries to 20. 
The Wattage can be around 400-500 Watts.
10 x 3Ah = 30 Ah.
1,5 x 10 =15 V.
15 x 30 = 450 Watts.
Would this work?

Comment: @CollageProject No because you are doing the math wrong. Ah is a measure of capacity and you use it as current. Or actually calculating the capacity in Wh. And your math says you are connecting 10 packs of 10 batteries which adds up to the 100 I already approximated in my answer. Rechargeables rarely are 1.5V, but could easily provide 10-20 A per cell.

Comment: The Ah rating can provide an idea of the current capacity. A 3 Ah 1.5V battery can usually provide 3A, which is defined as 1C. And it has a nominal power capacity of 4.5 Wh. Some lithium batteries can supply 10C to 20C, and some are even advertised as 50C, although that is likely for one time destructive use. And all batteries have internal resistance that limits maximum usable power. Lead-acid types are governed by the Peukert effect, such that at 1C the actual capacity is about 1/2 that of the rating at 1/20 C.